# Find all possible combinations with two differents arrays

Tags: php

```
$array1 = [null, 6, null];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4];
```

How do I find all possible unique combinations of these two lists (Should be the same lenght of array1 and keep the 6 in the same position);
Need to return

```
[1, 6, 2],[1, 6, 3],[1, 6, 4],[2, 6, 3],[2, 6, 4],[3, 6, 4]
```

Comment: ``$sets = []; for($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) { for($j = $i+1; $j < count($array2); $j++) { $sets[$i][] = array($array2[$i], 6, $array2[$j]); } }``

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/dpMomYznDiaTtdW4MXFSRQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic

```
$array1 = [null, 6, null];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4];
$final = [];
for($i = 0;$i < count($array2);$i++){
    for($j = $i + 1;$j < count($array2);$j++){
        for($k = 0;$k < count($array1);$k++){
            if(!is_null($array1[$k])){
                $final[] = [$array2[$i], $array1[$k], $array2[$j]];
            }
        }       
    }
}
print_r($final);
```